# hg push stuck at "sending pushkey command"

Tags: mercurial

Trying to push to hg server, but hangs on sending pushkey command, what could be the cause and how to resolve it?

```
[root@127]# hg push --debug
pushing to http://10.18.90.202:8000/
using http://10.18.90.202:8000/
sending capabilities command
query 1; heads
sending batch command
searching for changes
all remote heads known locally
no changes found
preparing listkeys for "phases"
sending listkeys command
preparing pushkey for "phases:facb00aff5573ed1767d2831910f0e4391dc7a4c"
sending pushkey command
sending 0 bytes
```

Comment: I would use a tool like Wireshark to find out, which side stops the communication.